# CSS Overlow doesn't appear to be honored

Tags: html, css

I have read a number of questions on here pertaining to the overflow property. It seems straightforward enough, but some basic expectations are not getting met.

Consider the code below. I've got a tall div specified as this:

`<div class="blue fixed-height1000">big</div>`

It appears inside another div that should be clipping it:

`<div class="cell yellow overflow-hidden fixed-height100">`

But the tall div is not clipping. Why?

My understanding would be that, since the parent is 100 pixels tall with no overflow allowed, then the child, which is 100 pixels tall, would not appear onscreen as 1000 pixels tall.

But that is not what is happening. The entire 1000 pixels are visible, causing the page to scroll.

Here are my guesses about why this is happening:

- The parent with the overflow property is a display:table-cell and overflow only works on display:block?
- Or, the parent is flexibly height because it is part of a table that fits to the page, and overflow only works on fixed sizes? (Even though for experimentation I tried to force a height on the table cell anyway to see if I could force the overflow to work)

```css
.fixed-width100 {width:100px;}
.fixed-height75 {height: 75px;}
.fixed-height1000 {height: 1000px;}
.height50percent {height: 50%;}
.height100percent {height:100%;}
.width100percent {width: 100%;}

.table {display: table;}
.row {display: table-row;}
.cell {display: table-cell;}

.overflow-hidden {overflow:hidden;}
.overflow-auto {overflow:auto;}
.overflow-scroll {overflow: scroll;}


.yellow {background-color: yellow;}
.orange {background-color: orange;}
.red {background-color: red;}
.green {background-color: green;}
.blue {background-color: blue;}
```

```html
<div class="height100percent">
<!--wraps entire page into a single table that fits to page-->
  <div class="width100percent height100percent table">

    <div class="row fixed-height75 green"> top header </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell fixed-width100 orange">fixed</div>
      <div class="cell yellow overflow-hidden fixed-height100">clipped?
        <div class="blue fixed-height1000">big</div>

      </div>
      <div class="cell red">
        <div class="height50percent green">
          height 50%
        </div>
        <div class="height50percent orange">
          height 50%
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">flex. </div>
      <div class="cell fixed-width100">fixed</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row fixed-height75 green">bottom footer</div>
  </div>             
</div>
```

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/11n900jm/) I slightly confused as to what you want to happen here?

Comment: @jbutler483 I want the tall div 1000 pixels in height to clip (excess be hidden) inside it's smaller parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your large content inside a div with `display:block;` set, as that honors overflow, while a table cell may not:

css: `.block100percent {display:block; height:100%;}`

```
<div class="cell yellow">
      <div class="block100percent overflow-auto red">
               <div class="blue fixed-height1000">big</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and actually the `display:block;` is optional as it is the default anyway

Answer (score 0):

I would say your problem is the display:table-cell. 
from w3schools:
"Let the element behave like a td element."
A td element adjust to the content and you can't really set a height on it and especially not hide the overflow :) 
As far as i know